# compile ffmpeg on stand redhat

Tags: ffmpeg, redhat

I'm working on a redhat server which isn't connected to the internet, so I can't download things directly onto the server. I can transfer them via SCP from another server.

Is there a step by step guide to compiling ffmpeg for redhat?

Comment: Ignore this stupid post of mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can scp from another server that is connected to the Internet and wish to install using rpm's rather than compiling, I suggest the following:

1. Install yum-downloadonly on the server in question:

   `yum -y install yum-downloadonly`
2. Simulate an install of ffmpeg using downloadonly to save all required packages locally:

   `yum -y install ffmpeg --downloadonly --downloaddir=your_download_directory`
3. Transfer all the downloaded rpm's to the server without Internet access
4. cd to the directory with the rpm's on that server and run this to install all of them:

   `rpm -ivh --nodeps *.rpm`

That should do it!